# APT: How to install recommended dependencies and not auto-remove them until the installing package is removed

Tags: debian, apt, debian-buster

Imagine a package `foo` that has a recommended dependency `bar` and a suggested dependency `baz`. How do I configure APT for the following behavior?

1. `apt install foo`: installs `foo` and `bar`; does not install `baz`
2. `apt autoremove`: no changes
3. `apt remove foo`: uninstalls `foo`
4. `apt autoremove`: uninstalls `bar`

I have tried setting these options in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-norecommends`:

```
APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant "false";
APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";
```

But, in the scenario above, this results in `bar` being uninstalled in step 2.

What is the right combination of APT configuration options to meet my goal?

**Update:** I've installed a fresh instance of Debian in a VM, made no config changes, and ran the following commands:

1. `apt update; apt upgrade`: nothing was out-of-date
2. `apt install exim4`: lots of stuff was installed (apologies for any typos, I transcribed these manually out of the VM)

   - `exim4-base`
   - `mariadb-common`
   - `libwrap0`
   - `libython2.7`
   - `exim4-daemon-light`
   - `libltd17`
   - `libunbound8`
   - `mailutils-common`
   - `libgsas17`
   - `psmisc`
   - `exim4-config`
   - `libntlm0`
   - `guile-2.2-libs`
   - `mailutils`
   - `mysql-common`
   - `libmailutils5`
   - `exim4`
   - `libevent-2.1-6`
   - `libmariadb3`
   - `libgc1c2`
   - `libgnutls-dane0`
   - `libkyotocabinet16v5`
   - `libfribidi0`
   - `liblz02-2`
3. `apt purge exim4`: `exim4` was uninstalled
4. `apt autoremove`: nothing was uninstalled

How do I get the other 23 packages to be removed automatically? I don't want to be looking back in my apt logs to try to reconstruct what needs to be done to fully reverse an `apt install {...}` command, especially if there were intervening installations that could require some of the automatically-installed packages.

By the way, this clearly conflicts with the man page for `apt-get`:

> remove
>
> remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed.
>
> purge
>
> purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged

My testing above shows that `install` and `remove`/`purge` are not symmetric as stated there.

Comment: What you ask for - except not to install recommendations - is standard apt. I'm afraid your changes did more harm then good.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've updated my question with a concrete example demonstrating the behavior I would like to obtain

Comment: Again: you wish for standard behaviour. Check your config for changes.

Comment: This is happening in a completely fresh virtual machine installed from the official Debian ISO that I downloaded this evening. I've made no config changes. I agree with you that the behavior I want seems expected, but it's not working that way for me.

Comment: I wondered why this has never bothered me.  I just realized that since my first day on Linux ('98 I think), I had Install-Recoommends and -Suggest on false.  You are correct: auto-remove and -clean only act on depending packages.  I suggest you run a cleanup yourself based on the output of "apt-cache depends exim4", filtering the suggests and recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of my continued confusion on this, I filed a bug with apt https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=981168. Of course, it turns out not to be a bug and to have a reasonable explanation. Quoting from the helpful maintainer Julian Andres Klode (I had given the same example of installing and then uninstalling `exim4` as in my question here):

> Most likely:
>
> exim4 depends on an exim4-daemon-$something, all of which provide
> mail-transport-agent. If one installed package
> depends/recommends/suggests mail-transport-agent, it won't be
> autoremoved.
>
> This is not a bug, and we might eventually get a cool feature to undo
> history, but it's not there yet, and I don't want to track it in a
> bug.

In addition:

> As a bonus point; I do have a system cleanup script that removes as
> many automatically installed packages as possible while keeping all
> manually insttalled ones:
>
> http://salsa.debian.org/jak/cleanup
>
> Clone that, install clasp, and run ./program_builder.py to have it
> give you a list of packages that can be removed.
>
> This is very thorough and a lot less safe than apt's autoremove.
>
> I need to work on adding a clasp solving backend to apt, then we can
> have a thorough autoremove code in apt too (and solve dependencies and
> order installations as best as possible :D).

Sounds like someday this may get implemented, but until then we might have to look through our APT logs or use the mentioned cleanup script.

Answer (score 2):

Thes are the settings you need:

```
APT::Get::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Get::Install-Suggests "false";
```

Comment: I still want to install the recommend and suggests at installation time, but I would also like them to be uninstalled at removal time.

Comment: Apt will warn you on next use about such packages, telling you to run "apt autoremove".

Comment: I ran `apt autoremove`; nothing was removed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `apt-mark hold` to prevent the desired package from being removed when executing `purge` or `remove`.

man apt-mark:

```
PREVENT CHANGES FOR A PACKAGE

hold
   hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent
the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.
```

You have already the list of `Suggest` packages list: `package.list`

```
cat package.list |xargs sudo apt-mark hold
```

2. Before executing `sudo apt autoremove` unhold them:

   ```
   cat package.list |xargs sudo apt-mark unhold
   ```